# почему то не работает delete[]

Tags: c++

почему то при добавлении 2йки когда в add вызывается setsize ,delete[] вызывает ошибку
не понимаю из за чего это.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include "Mnoj.h"
    int main()
    {
        int a = 5;
        Mnoj g(a);
        g += 8;
        g += 2;
    }
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
class Mnoj
{
    int n = 0;
    int* m = 0;
public:
    void setsize(int k)
    {
        int* a = new int[k];
        if (n > k)
            n = k;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            a[i] = m[i];
        n = k;
        delete[] this->m;
        m = a;
    }
    Mnoj()
    {}
    Mnoj(const int a) :n(1),m(new int[1])
    {
        m[0] = a;
    }
    
    Mnoj(const Mnoj& a) :n(a.n), m(new int[a.n])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            m[i] = a.m[i];
    }
    ~Mnoj()
    {
        delete[] m;
    }
    bool Check(int a) const
    {
        bool b = false;
        for (int i = 0; (i < n)&&(!b); ++i)
            if (m[i] == a)
                b = true;
        return b;
    }
    int size() const
    {
        return n;
    }
    void add(int a)
    {
        if (!Check(a))
        {
            setsize(n + 1);
            m[n] = a;
        }
    }
    Mnoj& operator +=(const int a)
    {
        add(a);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Comment: А вы думали о  смысле  вашего класса?  Если цель учебная, то все равно, с самого начала нужно учиться написать такие классы, чьи экземпляры будут  представлять осмысленную сущность и быть полезным.....

Comment: это класс-множество чисел, цель -учебная, я не выложил сюда все методы этого класса, в чем на ваш взгляд его проблема?

Comment: Возьмем один пример _ метод `setsize`. Там написано  `if (n > k) n = k;` А потом,  вне зависимости этого условия  это присваивание производится.  Каков смысл тогда в условии? А  логичней только при не  выполнении  этого условия выделять новую память. Метод `Check` проверяет есть ли такое значение в массиве(у вас множество есть именно массив), но если вам нужно будет  знать индекс этого элемента, придется снова полистать массив. Так пусть `Check`  сразу возвратит индекс или *указатель*. И т.д. и т.п.

Comment: n=k делается перед циклом от 0 до n, есть 2 варианта либо k<n либо n<k, мне нужно крутить цикл до меньшего из этих 2х значений, и если у меня например k>n я сначала прокручу цикл о старым n, только потом сделаю n=k, а в ином случае придется наоборот сначала присвоить потом идти в цикл, решить эту проблему можно разными способами, если у вас есть вариант лучше я с удовольствием возьму на заметку. По поводу check, у множества нет порядка элементов, соответственно как бы я не задал свое множество внутри класса, пользователь не должен требовать какой либо индекс элемента.

Comment: цикл со старым*

Answer (score 0):

```
void add(int a)
{
    if (!Check(a))
    {

        setsize(n + 1);
        // здесь n уже увеличился на единицу

        // а здесь неправильный доступ к памяти
        m[n] = a;

        // правильно так :
        m[n-1] = a;
    }
}
```